# Attach File Sharepoint Online List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I need create a column for attach files on my Sharepoint Online (365) for create a powerapp with this field and store this on my sharepoint.

On sharepoint list not exists a File or Blob Type. How can i add Attachment to a sharepoint list and store this?

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint provides OOB attachment field, if you enable attachments for list(list settings->advanced settings).

[image]

[image]